Cache multipart form data on Flutter (Contains multiple Images and lists)
I want to cache data locally.
Here is my function
For Image I converted in XFile
  XFile selectedShopImage = XFile("");
  XFile selectedDrugLicenseImage = XFile("");
  XFile selectedTradeLicenseImage = XFile("");

For Image Upload
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: const Center(child: Text("Choose an option")),
                  content: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ListBody(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/icons/camera.png',
                                height: 60,
                                width: 60,
                              ),
                              onTap: () async {
                                final pickedFile =
                                    await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                                  source: ImageSource.camera,
                                  imageQuality: 10,
                                );
                                if (pickedFile != null) {
                                  controller.selectedDrugLicenseImage =
                                      XFile(pickedFile.path);
                                }
                                Get.back();
                              },
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/icons/gallery.png',
                                height: 60,
                                width: 60,
                              ),
                              onTap: () async {
                                final pickedFile =
                                    await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                                  source: ImageSource.gallery,
                                  imageQuality: 10,
                                );
                                if (pickedFile != null) {
                                  controller.selectedDrugLicenseImage =
                                      XFile(pickedFile.path);
                                }
                                Get.back();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 0),
            height: 40,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 6,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Drug License Image',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

This is my Add Customer which I want to cache
// Add Customer
  Future<void> addCustomer() async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    diox.FormData data;

    String shopImage = selectedShopImage.path.split('/').last;
    String tradeLicenseImage = selectedTradeLicenseImage.path.split('/').last;
    String drugLicenseImage = selectedDrugLicenseImage.path.split('/').last;

    data = diox.FormData.fromMap({

      "token": MySharedPref.getToken("token".obs).toString(),
      "name": customerNameController.value.text.trim(),
      "code": customerCodeController.value.text.trim(),
      "phone": customerPhoneController.value.text.trim(),
      "address": customerAddressController.value.text.trim(),
      "street": customerAddress1Controller.value.text.trim(),
      "lat": latitude,
      "long": longitude,
      "postal_code": selectedPostalCodeBySubDistrict.value?.id.toString(),
      "cust_district_id": selectedDistrictOnly.value?.id.toString(),
      "cust_upazila_id": selectedSubDistrictOnly.value?.id.toString(),
      "email": customerEmailController.value.text.trim().toString(),
      "website": customerWebSiteController.value.text.trim().toString(),
      "estd_year": customerESTDYearController.value.text.trim().toString(),
      "nid_no": ownerNidController.value.text.trim(),
      "remarks": remarksController.value.text.trim(),
      "owner_name": ownerNameController.value.text.trim(),
      "owner_phone": ownerPhoneController.value.text.trim(),
      "owner_email": ownerEmailController.value.text.trim(),
      "ownership_type_id": selectedOwnershipList.value?.id.toString(),
      "contact_person_name": contactPersonNameController.value.text.trim(),
      "contact_person_phone": contactPersonPhoneController.value.text.trim(),
      "contact_person_email": contactPersonEmailController.value.text.trim(),
      "contact_person_designation_id":
      contactPersonDesignationIdController.value.text.trim(),
      "customer_type_id": selectedCustomerCategory.value?.id.toString(),
      "customer_category_id": selectedPriceGroupList.value?.id.toString(),
      "payment_method_id": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "tin_no": tinController.value.text.trim(),
      "bin_no": binController.value.text.trim(),
      "shop_image": await diox.MultipartFile.fromFile(selectedShopImage.path,
          filename: shopImage, contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpg")),
      "account_name[]": accountNames,
      "account_number[]": accountNumbers,
      "bank_name[]": bankNames,
      "branch[]": branchNames,
      "swift_code[]": swiftCodes,
      "routing_number[]": routingNumbers,
      "employee_count": employeeNumberController.value.text.trim(),
      "shop_size": shopSizeController.value.text.trim(),
      "aircondition": airConditionValue.value ? 1 : 0,
      "power_backup": powerBackupValue.value ? 1 : 0,
      "refrigerator": refrigeratorValue.value ? 1 : 0,
      "license_number": tradeLicenseNumberController.value.text.trim(),
      "issued_date": tradeLicenseIssueDate.text.toString(),
      "validity_date": tradeLicenseValidityDate.text.toString(),
      "attachment": await diox.MultipartFile.fromFile(selectedTradeLicenseImage.path,
          filename: tradeLicenseImage, contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpg")),
      "license_number1": drugLicenseNumberController.value.text.trim(),
      "issued_date1": drugLicenseIssueDate.text.toString(),
      "validity_date1": drugLicenseValidityDate.text.toString(),

      "country_id": marketStructureController.marketStructure.value.data!.marketSetup!.countryId,
      "division_id": marketStructureController.marketStructure.value.data!.marketSetup!.divisionId,
      "district_id": marketStructureController.marketStructure.value.data!.marketSetup!.districtId,
      "upazila_id": marketStructureController.marketStructure.value.data!.marketSetup!.upazilaId,
      "union_id": marketStructureController.marketStructure.value.data!.marketSetup!.unionId,
      "market_id": marketStructureController.marketStructure.value.data!.marketSetup!.marketId,
      "sub_market_id": marketStructureController.marketStructure.value.data!.marketSetup!.subMarketId,

      "attachment1": await diox.MultipartFile.fromFile(selectedDrugLicenseImage.path,
          filename: drugLicenseImage, contentType: new MediaType("image", "jpg")),
    });

    await ApiClient.safeApiCall(
      AppUrls.addCustomer,
      RequestType.post,
      queryParameters: {
        "token": MySharedPref.getToken("token".obs).toString(),
      },
      headers: {"hrm_api_key": prefs.getString('key')},
      data: data,
      onSuccess: (response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          if (response.data['status'] == false) {
            customToast(msg: "Failed", color: Colors.red);
          } else {
            customToast(msg: "Account added successfully", color: Colors.green);
          }
        }
      },
    );
    isLoading.value = false;
  }

The Function I want to store as cache.
I was using for caching get request.
flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.2
I want to store the data 1st then when I want i should be able to submit the data to the server.
I have no idea how should I do this.
